# jQuery Weather Underground API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, http

I am trying to make a simple javascript weather app with the Weather Underground API. I have a working jQuery HTTP request for weather based on latitude and longitude, pulled from the browser's geolocation. I want to be able to enter a zipcode for weather as well, WU offers a geolookup to get the coordinates from a zipcode, but my JSON request won't work, even though it looks exactly the same as my working request.

The request URL works when manually entered in a browser.

```
    function getCurrentLocation(zip){

    var apiKey = myApiKey;

    var link = 
    "http://api.wunderground.com/api/myApiKey/geolookup/q/94025.json";

    console.log(link);

    $.getJSON(link, function(json) {

    console.log(json);
    })}

   var zip = '59901';
   getCurrentLocation(zip)
```

Thank you in advanced, I am very new to JS and appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are actually adding your api key. Also concat url properly with api key and zip code.

```
function getCurrentLocation(zip){

 var apiKey = 'api key';

 var link = 
 "//api.wunderground.com/api/"+apiKey+"/geolookup/q/"+zip+".json";

 console.log(link);

 $.getJSON(link, function(json) {

 console.log(json);
 })
}

var zip = '59901';
getCurrentLocation(zip)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I do have my actual API key in the code, I just didn't want to put it online. I had the concatenated link printed in the console, and copy and pasted that into a browser, and it worked fine then.

Comment: I have tested it and it works fine with `$.getJSON`, check in your console if you are getting any error.